# python folium heatmap not displaying

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I'm trying to create a heatmap from geographic point data using `folium` but can't make the map display. The data called `df` looks like this:

```
 lon          lat
-70.979868  -33.679843
-70.969798  -33.673900
-70.969040  -33.696048
-70.947613  -33.678202
-70.940072  -33.674478
```

I create the base map using `Map`:

```
from folium import Map
from folium.plugins import HeatMap    
hmap = Map(location=[-33.45, -70.65], control_scale=True, zoom_start=11, )
```

And then create a layer on top using `HeatMap`:

```
hm_ap = HeatMap(list(zip(df.lat.values, df.lon.values)), 
                radius=8, max_zoom=13).add_to(hm_ap)
hm_ap
```

The code apparently works, but the output is the following:

```
<folium.plugins.heat_map.HeatMap at 0x21cd9088588>
```

You know why the map is not being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be adding the heatmap layer to itself (`.add_to(hm_ap)`), but you need to add it to the map (which is `hmap`).

First you create your map:

```py
from folium import Map
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

hmap = Map(location=[-33.45, -70.65], control_scale=True, zoom_start=11)
```

Then you create your HeatMap layer and add it to the map:

```py
heatmap_layer = HeatMap(list(zip(df.lat.values, df.lon.values)), 
                radius=8, max_zoom=13)
heatmap_layer.add_to(hmap)
```

Then you should be able to view it:

```
hmap
```